# HTML hyperlink remain changed color after mouse has moved over link

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, hyperlink

I was wondering, I have links that change blue when a mouse hovers over them. Would it be possible to make them remain blue a few seconds after the mouse has moved away? I'm guessing this would be possible with jquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative might be the CSS transition-duration property. This won't keep it a solid color for the specified time but it can allow a transition from one color to another to take a number of seconds for example. This may not be supported by some browsers visiting the page so the other answers using jQuery are great for that.

```
a {
    color: red;
    transition-duration: 5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Ya its not that important. This works great in FF and Chrome. Good enough :) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sure!  If you want to have the link fade out, you'll need jQuery UI to animate the color:

```
$('#myLinkId').hover(
  function(e){
    //mouseover
    $(this).css('color','blue');
  },
  function(e){
    //mouseout
    $(this).animate({color:'black'},300); //300 is the speed of the animation in ms
  }
);
```

Animate docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You need jQuery UI to animate colors.

Comment: using another plugin for a simple task? I really think you need jQuery UI on this...

Comment: Hmm interesting! I can't seem to get this to work. Does this seem Correct? http://pastebin.com/4MYJD3mD  (As you can tell, I am noob to jquery. Do i need to install jQuery Ui plugin?

Comment: Yeah, to use my solution you'll need to install the UI plugin, or use the setTimeout version of the mouseOut function posted by Reigel above.  You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mXkXn/

Comment: CSS3 has the transition rule too, of course it only works in browsers that support it.

Answer (score 4):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JEPJS/)

css

```
a {
  color: red;
}

a.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

html

```
<a href="index.html">home</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').hover(function(){
       $(this).addClass('blue');
   },
   function(){
       var link = $(this);
       setTimeout(function(){link.removeClass('blue');},1000); 
   })
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JEPJS/)

Comment: Very nice, I'm going to use this!

Comment: Any way to make it fade out, rather than just switch back after 1000ms? (Sorry i didnt mention in question)